# Notation of field extensions and ring extensions

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

For example the notation for rings like the Gaussian integers uses brackets: $\mathbb{Z}[i]$.

Yet the notation for field extensions uses parentheses, like in the case of the Gaussian rationals $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

But why?

In both cases we have
$$ \mathbb{Z}[i] = \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2 + 1) \\
 \mathbb{Q}[i] = \mathbb{Q}[X]/(X^2 + 1) \, .$$

Is it just convention, or is there any deeper meaning that I'm missing?

Comment: As far as I know it's just a convention which indicates that one is a field with the added element, while the other is not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Typically the notation $R[\alpha]$ means that we are adjoining the element $\alpha$ to some a ring $R$. However, $R(\alpha)$ means that we are adjoining the element $\alpha$ and $\alpha^{-1}$ to the ring $R$. But when we are adjoining roots of polynomials, we get inverses for free, because if we are adjoining the root $r$ of some polynomial $p(z) = a_nz^n +.... + a_0$, then
$$
r(a_n r^{n-1} + ... + a_1) = - a_0.
$$
Typically, $-a_0$ will be invertible in our ring, and so $r$ is invertible. One specific instance of this is that $\mathbb{Q}(i) = \mathbb{Q}[i]$.

A case where they would not be the same is $\mathbb{Q}[t]$ and $\mathbb{Q}(t)$, where $t$ is a transcendental element over $\mathbb{Q}$. The former would just be isomorphic to the ring of polynomials with $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients, which is not a field. The latter would be the field of rational functions with $\mathbb{Q}$ coefficients.

While I'm not sure if this reasoning is standard, I was exposed to this idea by an algebra professor of mine. I trust his knowledge of the conventions a bit better than my own.

Comment: When dealing with fields extension, perhaps it is important to stress the fact that it is a theorem, and a rather important and easy to prove one, that if $\;F\subset K\;$ are fields and $\;k\in K\;$,  then $\;F[k]=F(k)\iff  k\;$ is *algebraic* over $\;F\;$ .

Comment: You're completely right. Thanks for pointing that out. I thought that hinting at that result would be enough, but for reference and future reading, I'm glad that you included it.

Comment: Should we add that if $R$ is a ring, then $R(a)$ denotes the [field of fractions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_of_fractions) of $R[a]$? (As you pointed out, they are generally distinct).